# Calling a Python class function from ExternalEvaluate

Tags: python, external-calls

I am attempting to use ExternalEvaluate to use some python packages ([ARC](https://arc-alkali-rydberg-calculator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to save me some effort in performing the calculations in Mathematica, and for the most part I think it works as intended.
The issue is not with the specific python package, but I will keep it here for the example.

I am having an issue with calling one class function which throws an error about the positional arguments.
In python the code would look just like this:

```
atom = arc.Rubidium87()
groundState = arc.DynamicPolarizability(atom, 5, 0, 0.5)
groundState.defineBasis(5, 25)
```

And it runs flawlessly.

In Mathematica I have the following:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[session, {"atom = arc.Rubidium87()","atom=arc.Rubidium87()"}]
setDynamicPolarizability[n_, l_, j_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, <|"Command" -> "gs=arc.DynamicPolarizability","Arguments" -> {"atom", n, l, j}|>]

setDynamicPolarizability[5, 0, 0.5];
setBasis[n_, nmax_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, <|"Command" -> "gs.defineBasis","Arguments" -> {n, nmax}|>]
setBasis[5, 25]
```

however the final line of code throws an error

[image: ![ErrorMessage]

I clearly have both of the required arguments for the function, and the previous things I have tried have worked perfectly fine. I have a feeling that it is due to the fact that it is a class function ([docs](https://arc-alkali-rydberg-calculator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/arc.calculations_atom_single.DynamicPolarizability.defineBasis.html#arc.calculations_atom_single.DynamicPolarizability.defineBasis), [source](https://arc-alkali-rydberg-calculator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/arc/calculations_atom_single.html#DynamicPolarizability.defineBasis)) and the missing `self` is the cause of the problem.

I hope the problem I'm having is clear, any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me the problem is not directly about the `self` but rather the way commands are executed. Consider this example before solving the problem.

let's say you want to assign a variable, the sum of two numbers:

#### non-interactive method

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "
import operator
temp = operator.add(1,2)
temp
"]

(* Out: 3 *)
```

#### Interactive method

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];

ExternalEvaluate[session, "import operator"];

ExternalEvaluate[session, <|"Command" -> "temp = operator.add", "Arguments" -> {1, 2}|>]

(* Out: Error *)
```

[image]

What happened? It seems `"temp = operator.add"` is not executed as we might think. So one workaround is to define an intermediary function:

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, <|"Command" -> "
def temp(a,b):
    global sample
    sample=operator.add(a,b)
", "Arguments" -> {1, 3}|>]

ExternalValue[session, "sample"]

(* Out: 4 *)
```

Back to your question, I think `"gs"` is not initialized (`gs=arc.DynamicPolarizability` is executed), when you call with 2 arguments, it doesn't match to `(self,arg1,arg2)` pattern. We could solve it using the above method:

```
ClearAll[setDynamicPolarizability,setBasis];

ExternalEvaluate[session, "
import arc
atom=arc.Rubidium87()
"]

setDynamicPolarizability[n_, l_, j_] := 
 ExternalEvaluate[session, <|"Command" -> "
gs=None
def temp2(a,b,c):
    global gs
    gs=arc.DynamicPolarizability(atom,a,b,c)
", "Arguments" -> {n, l, j}|>]

setDynamicPolarizability[5, 0, 0.5];

setBasis[n_, nmax_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, <|"Command" -> "
def temp4(a,b):
    global gs
    return gs.defineBasis(a,b)
", "Arguments" -> {n, nmax}|>]

setBasis[5, 25]
```

works as expected.

And lastly:

```
DeleteObject[session];
```

#### Notes:

- In Python use `global` to manipulate global variables rather than creating an in-scope variable
- If you should define multiple functions, pick unique names to prevent mixing up
- Code was tested on Mathematica 13.0 with Python 3.10 on Windows 10

If you found a better solution, don't forget to share it with the community.

Comment: In my experience, the last bullet point isn't necessary.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov you're right, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was not understanding with all of this, this helps me very much.

Comment: Apologies if this is a simple question, I have implemented the above example you posted, however each function call of setBasis and setDynamicPolarizability is just outputting Null[5,25] and Null[5,0,0.5]. Using ExternalValue[session,"gs"] also returns nothing, saying that gs is not defined.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: @D.Brown in the above code, `setDynamicPolarizability` does not return anything in python, it just manipulates global objects, which also could be applied to the `setBasis` (I think the `return` keyword is redundant in your case and could be removed). I execute the above code in a fresh kernel and after each call, `ExternalValue[session, "gs"]` was a `PythonObject`. I suggest you do the same, start a fresh kernel and run the above code.

Comment: @BenIzd Thank you very much. I have run the above example, removed the `return` keyword and placed `ExternalValue[session, "gs"]` after each call and nothing is returned each time. 

I am wondering if there is something missing with my Python or Mathematica installations that makes this the case. I will see if this is true.

Thank you very much for the assistance

Answer (score 7):

It is an extended comment to the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/263056/280) by [Ben Izd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/77079/ben-izd).

The simplest *interactive* solution for his example is as follows:

```
session = StartExternalSession[<|"System" -> "Python",
                                 "SessionProlog" -> "import operator"|>]

addTwo = ExternalFunction[session, "operator.add"]
```

> [image]

You can use it as follows:

```
addTwo[2, 3]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

The simplest *non-interactive* solution:

```
addTwo = ExternalFunction["Python", "import operator;  operator.add"]
```

> [image]

Usage is the same (but works slower, because Python session is new for every call):

```
addTwo[2, 3]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is incredibly helpful